# Footer Component wrong position in React Router 4 and Layout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, layout, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I am using react router 4.3.1 with React of course, i have created a Layout component, my different content components renders ok whith {this.props.Children} but i cant seem to succed in placing the Footer component at the bottom of all the Layout, even if it is in a new div and "outside" all the logic, my Footer component is the third form top to bottom, at the bottom theres the content. I have been fighting with this for a lot of weeks with no luck, here it my code.

Routes component.-

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Layout from './components/Layout';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Whoweare from './components/Whoweare';
import Services from './components/Services';
import Contact from './components/Contact';
import Errornotfound from './components/Errornotfound';

export default function Routes() {

    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div>
                <Route component={ Layout }/>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/' component={ Home } />
                    <Route path='/whoweare' component={ Whoweare } />
                    <Route path='/services' component={ Services } />
                    <Route path='/contact' component={ Contact } />
                    <Route component={ Errornotfound } />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}
```

Finally this is my simple Layout component.-

As you can notice Footer is the last component, but even though it is not displayed at the bottom.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Navbars from './Navbars';

import Header from './Header';
import Banners from './Banners';
import Footer from './Footer';

export default class Layout extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <col>
                    <Header/>
                    <div>
                        <col>
                            <Navbars/>
                        </col>
                        <Banners/>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <col>
                            {this.props.Children}
                        </col>
                    </div>
                        <Footer/>
                </col>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Thank you for everything in advance, somehow i cannot find the solution for this, not even with a new div in the Layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently `Layout` doesn't have any children. You are putting the entire `Switch` with your content components after `Layout`.

Instead of the following:

```
        <Route component={ Layout }/>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={ Home } />
            <Route path='/whoweare' component={ Whoweare } />
            <Route path='/services' component={ Services } />
            <Route path='/contact' component={ Contact } />
            <Route component={ Errornotfound } />
        </Switch>
```

it seems that you meant to do something more like:

```
<Layout>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={ Home } />
        <Route path='/whoweare' component={ Whoweare } />
        <Route path='/services' component={ Services } />
        <Route path='/contact' component={ Contact } />
        <Route component={ Errornotfound } />
    </Switch>
</Layout>
```

You also need to fix `{this.props.Children}`. It should be `{this.props.children}` -- this will matter once `Layout` has children.

Comment: Yes, @Ryan Cogswell i thought i had already tried that but apparently i didnt, that was the solution, thank you very much, have a nice day.